# Is there anything similar to the OS X InputManager on Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, winapi

Is there anything similar on Windows what would achieve the same as the InputManager on OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to inject code into processes (which is what Input Managers are most commonly used for), the Windows equivalents are:

- `AppInit_DLLs` to automatically load your DLL into new processes,
- `CreateRemoteThread` to start a new thread in a particular existing process, and
- `SetWindowsHookEx` to allow the capture of window events (keyboard, mouse, window creating, drawing, etc).

All of these methods require a DLL which will be injected into the remote process. C would be the best language to write such a DLL in as such a DLL needs to be quite light weight as to not bog the system down. RPC methods such as named pipes can be used to communicate to a master process should this be required.

Googling for these three APIs will turn up general sample code for these methods.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Windows has an API that developers can use to create new kinds of text input systems.  I gather there are a wide variety of text input systems in use in non-Roman-derived markets, many of which are provided by third parties.

It's unclear if that's what you were really asking about, though, because you just assumed everyone knows what you would want to use an Input Manager for on Mac OS X.

- If you want to create a new type of input method, ask how to do that.
- If you want to get your own code running inside other applications, ask how to do that.

Don't just assume people can read your mind when asking questions, and don't assume that they have the same experience that you do and will recognize all the same platform-specific terminology.